# Python SQL database query giving "Too few parameters" error

Tags: python, sql, ms-access

I have the following code which is attempting to pull several SQL queries from an Access database

```
import pyodbc
import datetime

conx = pyodbc.connect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\\Users\\Stuart\\PycharmProjects\\untitled\\Databases\\SandP.accdb;")

cursor=conx.cursor()

query=""" SELECT DISTINCT Date_ FROM Closing_prices
     WHERE Date_ >= ? AND Date_ < ?"""

params1 = (datetime.date(2011, 8, 10), datetime.date(2014, 4, 30))
cursor.execute(query, params1)

dates = list()
for date in cursor:
    dates.append(date[0])

for date in dates:
    params2 = date
    cursor = conx.cursor()

    query= '''SELECT Volatility,Last_price FROM Volatility v,Closing_prices c WHERE c.Date_= ? and v.Date_=c.Date_'''
    cursor.execute(query,params2)

    for (vol,price) in cursor:
        volatility=float(vol)
        closing_price=float(price)
    cursor.close()

    cursor = conx.cursor()
    if (date.weekday()==4):
        nextDay=(date + datetime.timedelta(days=3))
    else:
        nextDay=(date + datetime.timedelta(days=1))

    query= '''SELECT Date_,Time_, Close_ FROM Intraday_values WHERE (date = ? and time >= ?) or (date = ? and time <= ?)'''

    params3 = (date,datetime.time(15, 30),nextDay,datetime.time(15, 14))
    cursor.execute(query,params3)
```

This last bit is throwing up the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Stuart/PycharmProjects/untitled/Apache - Copy.py", line 67, in <module>
cursor.execute(query,params3)
pyodbc.Error: ('07002', '[07002] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 6. (-3010) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

The request is attempting to pull out the Date_, Time_ and Close_ items from the table, for the dates passed to the request as it iterates through the list of dates created previously, along with cut off times of "after 15:30 for "date" and "before 15:14" for "date+1".

Firstly, why would this be expecting 6 parameters when there are only 4 question marks (?) in the SQL request - have I not formed this properly?

Also, I took a stab at the parameter creation for a datetime.time. Is this incorrectly formed also?

I'm a bit out of my depth!

Comment: In your last (troublesome) query, are `date` and `time` the names of actual fields in the table, or should your WHERE clause really be referring to `Date_` and `Time_`? (BTW, your usage of `datetime.time()` should work fine.)

Comment: Ah that was the nudge in the right direction I needed, I changed it to query= '''SELECT Date_,Time_, Close_ FROM Intraday_values WHERE (Date_ = ? and Time_ >= ?) or (Date_ = ? and Time_ <= ?)''' which now works. It seems so simple now with help...but had me stumped. Again, your help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: I would have used [str.format()](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/string.html) in the query string, passing the date and time values rather than using cursor parameters. Less reliant on the database (Jet) but more processing on the client (Python). But just a preference -to each his own!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works after changing the query 
to

```
query= '''SELECT Date_,Time_, Close_
          FROM Intraday_values
          WHERE (Date_ = ? and Time_ >= ?)
                OR (Date_ = ? and Time_ <= ?)'''
```