# Selecting a field of the time data type using pyodbc

Tags: python, sql, ms-access, pyodbc

When I select a field of the time data type (from an MS ACCESS database) using the `pyodbc` module, I receive a strange format. When I run the query directly in access it shows in the `HH:MM:SS` format as expected.

My SQL query:

```
SELECT [F].float, [I].time_inserted
FROM [Float] AS F, Insersion AS I
WHERE F.floaterID = I.floaterID;
```

My DDL query for the Insersion table:

```
CREATE TABLE Insersion (
insersionID COUNTER PRIMARY KEY, 
date_inserted DATE, 
time_inserted TIME, 
floaterID INT, 
wholeID INT, 
FOREIGN KEY (floaterID) REFERENCES [Float] (floaterID), 
FOREIGN KEY (wholeID) REFERENCES [whole] (wholeID), 
conversionType VARCHAR(30))
```

Python:

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(query)
for row in cursor.fetchall():
     print(row)
```

Expected: 12:14:29

Reality: datetime.datetime(1899, 12, 30, 12, 14, 29)

Expected: 12:16:39

Reality: datetime.datetime(1899, 12, 30, 12, 16, 39)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is behaving as expected.

Access doesn't have a `Time` field, only `DateTime`, and uses 1899-12-30 00:00:00 as their reference time. So a field with only a date specified, will come over as that date on 1899-12-30. You can just ignore the date part.

Also see: [Inserting time into MS Access with python odbc](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28751539)

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, sorry if this is obvious, but how do you selectively ignore the date and vice versa if you're selecting the date instead, will I need to use python or is there a way to do it with the SQL?

Comment: You do this in Python, since Access has no notion of only a time (or only a date). See https://stackoverflow.com/q/29324824. While you can convert to a string in SQL, then it's a string containing the time, not a time object.