# PYODBC - Too Few Parameters

Tags: python, sql, pyodbc

I have the following code:

```
Late_Students = cursor.execute('''
    SELECT Student.Forename, Student.Surname, FORMAT(Event_Date_Time,"Long Time") AS Time_Of_Event
    FROM Events, Student
    WHERE FORMAT(Event_Date_Time,"Short Date") = Date()
    AND Events.RFID = Student.RFID AND
    Events.In_Or_Out = ?
    AND FORMAT(Event_Date_Time,"Long Time")>#08:40:00#''','In')

rows = cursor.fetchall()
print(rows)
```

It's a really simple and I have many in my program like it, however when I run the program, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...Coursework System 1.8.py", line 104, in <module>
    AND FORMAT(Event_Date_Time,"Long Time")>#08:40:00#''','In')
pyodbc.Error: ('07002', '[07002] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]
                         Too few parameters. Expected 3. (-3010) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

When I add parameters, I get the following error telling me I have too many parameters:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\Coursework System 1.8.py", line 104, in <module>
    AND FORMAT(Event_Date_Time,"Long Time")>#08:40:00#''','In','','')
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('The SQL contains 1 parameter markers, but 3
                           parameters were supplied', 'HY000')
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Working with dates in Access using pyodbc giving "Too few parameters" error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28568110/working-with-dates-in-access-using-pyodbc-giving-too-few-parameters-error)

Comment: @PeterWood I've tried the solution posted there, but to no avail. For some reason it is still not working.

Comment: What error do you get then?

Comment: The same error as before

Comment: Which error? Did you replace `#08:40:00#` with `?` and pass `datetime.time(8, 40)`?

Comment: Changing all the things within the query to parameters solved this problem. Thank you :)

Comment: You're very welcome (c:

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Too few parameters error, while no parameters placeholders used](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42834490/too-few-parameters-error-while-no-parameters-placeholders-used)

Answer (score 0):

```
Long_Time = 'Long Time'
Short_Date = 'Short Date'
Todays_Date = time.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
Reg_Time = str('#08:40:00#')
In = 'In'

Late_Students = '''
                SELECT Student.Forename, Student.Surname, FORMAT(Event_Date_Time,?) AS Time_Of_Event
                FROM Events, Student
                WHERE FORMAT(Event_Date_Time,?) =?
                AND Events.RFID = Student.RFID AND
                Events.In_Or_Out =?
                AND FORMAT(Event_Date_Time,?)>?'''

parameters = (Long_Time, Short_Date,Todays_Date, In, Long_Time, Reg_Time)
cursor.execute(Late_Students, parameters)
```